# Data Type of Columns in a List - R

Tags: r, dataset, mode

I want to "extract" the data types of the different columns in a list in R.

I'm using the following function:

```
my.data.types <- t(sapply(loansData,
             function(x) c(typeof(x), storage.mode(x), mode(x))))
```

However, the data types I'm getting are not the same as the data I have.

For example, loan.purpose stores strings but the result I get is the following:

```
loan.purpose                   "integer" "integer" "numeric"
```

How can I get the data types of my columns?

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: Well, it seems that class(x) is what I'm looking for. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Diego. Yep, `sapply (loansData, class)` is what you are looking for. However, this question is about programming rather than statistics, so I vote that it shoudl be migrated to stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you cbeleites. Yeah, sorry for posting this here... A little bit distracted. But well, kind of related tho :)

Comment: If this question has already been answered then please do us the favor of writing it as an answer and after a suitable interval checking it as answered. Otherwise many people will waste time reading through it.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by cbeleites the answer to this question is

```
sapply (loansData, class)
```